# var won't redefine itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am making a 2-player web game using HTML, CSS, jQuery and JS. The way my game works is that it's tic-tac-toe except when the table is full, you can replace a tile that was previously controlled by your opponent with a tile of your own. The problem is that I can't get the code to recognize that the table is full. He is a small example of my code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="left" ID="one1">
      <div class="playerclick" ID="red11"></div>
      <div class="playerclick" ID="blue11"></div>
  </td>
    <td ID="one2">
  <div class="playerclick" ID="red12"></div>
      <div class="playerclick" ID="blue12"></div>
  </td>
    <td ID="one3">
  <div class="playerclick" ID="red13"></div>
      <div class="playerclick" ID="blue13"></div>
  </td>
```

And here is the JS:

```
var turn = 'red';
var fullTable = 'no';
var redLines = 0;
var blueLines = 0;
var tile1 = 'noclick';
var tile1preClick = 'no';
var tile1justClick = 'no';
var tile2 = 'noclick';
var tile2preClick = 'no';
var tile2justClick = 'no';
var tile3 = 'noclick';
var tile3preClick = 'no';
var tile3justClick = 'no';
var folderIf = 'folder';

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#one1').click(function() {
$('#one1').click(function() {
   if (fullTable === 'no')
     {
       if (tile1 === 'noclick')
         {
       if (turn === 'red' && tile1preClick === 'no')
         {
           tile1 = 'red';
           $('#red11').css('opacity', '1');
           $('#one1').css('background', 'white');
           $('#one1').addClass('preclick');
           tile1preClick = 'yes';
           turn = 'blue';
         }
         if (turn === 'blue' && tile1preClick === 'no')
           {
             tile1 = 'blue';
             $('#blue11').css('opacity', '1');
             $('#one1').css('background', 'white');
             $('#one1').addClass('preclick');
             turn = 'red';
           }
         }
       $('.preclick').click(function(){
    if (fullTable === 'no')
      {
                   if (tile1preClick === 'yes' && tile2preClick === 'yes' && tile3preClick === 'yes')
{
  $('.preclick').removeClass('preclick');
  fullTable = 'yes';
}
        else {
        confirm('You can\'t claim this tile yet!');
      }
      }
  });
     }
   if (fullTable === 'yes')
     {
       if (tile1 === 'blue' && tile1justClick === 'no')
         {
           if (turn === 'red')
             {
               tile1 = 'red';
               $('#blue11').css('opacity', '0');
               $('#blue11').css('background', 'initial');
               $('#blue11').hide();
               $('#red11').show();
               $('#red11').css('background', '#FF0000');
               $('#red11').css('opacity', '1');
               $('#one1').css('background', 'white');
              if (folderIf === 'folder')
                 {
               $('#one1').removeClass('justclick');
                $('#one2').removeClass('justclick');
                   $('#one3').removeClass('justclick');
                 }
               $('#one1').addClass('justclick');
               if (folderIf === 'folder')
                 {
               tile1justClick = 'yes';
               tile2justClick = 'no';
               tile3justClick = 'no';
                 }
               turn = 'blue';
             }
         }
       if (tile1 === 'red' && tile1justClick === 'no')
         {
          if (turn === 'blue')
            {
              tile1 = 'blue';
              $('#red11').css('opacity', '0');
              $('#red11').css('background', 'initial');
               $('#red11').hide();
               $('#blue11').show();
               $('#blue11').css('background', 'blue');
               $('#blue11').css('opacity', '1');
               $('#one1').css('background', 'white');
               if (folderIf === 'folder')
                 {
               $('#one1').removeClass('justclick');
                $('#one2').removeClass('justclick');
                   $('#one3').removeClass('justclick');
                 }
               $('#one1').addClass('justclick');
              if (folderIf === 'folder')
                {
              tile1justClick = 'yes';
               tile2justClick = 'no';
               tile3justClick = 'no';
                }
              turn = 'red';
            }
         }
       $('.justclick').click(function() {
         confirm('You can\'t claim that tile yet!');
       });
     }
 });
})
```

I have no idea why this isn't working. Any help?
EDIT:
Wow, I didn't think that I'd get answers that quickly. To be more clear, the var fullTable is supposed to indicate to the game if the table is full. At the beginning, it is set to 'no' (I might change it to use booleans), and when all the tiles have been clicked, it will be set to 'yes', however, I can't get the program to recognize that the table is full. If the table isn't full, any tile that has already been clicked cannot be changed, but once the table is full it can be. 
Jaromanda X, thanks for telling me that it adds a .preclick or a .justclick every time the user clicks the tile. I will fix that now.

EDIT(2): Oh my gosh, I feel dumb. I was fixing the class adding and realized that blue doesn't change the variable tile1preClick to 'yes'. I'm pretty sure that I've solved this one on my own... Thanks for your answers.

Comment: which `var` won't `redefine itself` (whatever that means)

Comment: `'yes'` and `'no'`? You may be interested in the concept of [boolean values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) ([`true` and `false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Boolean_type)).

Comment: `$('#one1').click(function() {
$('#one1').click(function() {` - every time you click on the single tile with `id=one1` - you add yet another click handler to it - is that what you intended?